# GEN variables not identified - PARI library C

Tags: gcc, ubuntu-16.04, pari

I have recently installed PARI library on ubuntu 16.04. The set of examples provided with the source are running correctly but , if I use "gun", "ghalf", etc., gcc compilation fails with error :

error: ‘gun’ undeclared (first use in this function)

I am new to this library and know very little about it. Can anybody please help me in fixing this error.

This is the code that I am trying to compile :

```
#include<stdio.h>  
#include <pari/pari.h>  
int main(void)  
{  
 GEN i,j,k;  
 pari_init(500000,2);  
 i=gun;  
 j=stoi(3);  
 k=gadd(i,j);  
 printf("1+3=%s\n",GENtostr(k));  
 return 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using code intended for a very old version of PARI. Modern versions use `gen_1` rather than `gun` for the constant 1. With this change,

```
gcc -o test-pari test-pari.c -lpari && ./test-pari
```

yields

> 1+3=4

as desired. Alternatively (not recommended!), if you're trying to port a lot of old code, you could add

```
#define PARI_OLD_NAMES
```

before

```
#include <pari/pari.h>
```

and the code with work with `gun`.

Comment: Sorry it took so long for me to come across the question!